# Selenium xpath not getting selected in IE 11

Tags: selenium, xpath

Since i am from testing background and i have very minimal knowledge in coding i am facing a small issue with my automation of my application. I am unable to get the xpath for the element in IE11. Please find the below details :-

[the IE content screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxQMA.png)

Codes which i tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='WD91']")).click();
```

also

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Manage Device']")).click();
```

but i am getting the below error when tried to run :-

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.6.0.0
Listening on port 42278
Only local connections are allowed
Nov 09, 2017 6:39:27 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='WD91']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-/
```

Can anyone tell me if i am doing something wrong ?
Apologies in advance if my question is repetitive or is dumb. I would rally appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: The selector on `Manage Device` won't match - the text is pluralized, and you'll need to account for whitespace too. Suggest use `.contains()` instead of an exact comparison. But your xpath for `@WD91` should work, although would suggest a more specific selector, like `//a[@id='WD91']`

Comment: Try adding this capability while initialising InternetExplorer driver. capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

Comment: I tried with the code driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='WD91']")).click(); also 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(Link(), 'Manage Devices')]")).click(); also 
 driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Manage Devices")).click();       I still get the error :(

Comment: @Manmohan_singh also tried setting the capabilities but the issue still remains :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your xpath is correct , but try to use ID and also include wait if required

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement ElementBtn= driver.findElement(By.id("WD91"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ElementBtn));
ElementBtn.click();
```

OR using xpath

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement ElementBtn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='WD91']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ElementBtn));
ElementBtn.click();
```

OR try JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement ElementBtn= driver.findElement(By.id("WD91"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ElementBtn);
```

Comment: Again the same issue for all the 3 suggestions 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #WD91
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:12:07.291Z'

Comment: Where are u using css selector I gave code using xpath and ID

Comment: for the first suggestion it worked for the first try... then when i tried again its giving me the same error :(

Comment: Strange if it is worked in first try then should work in second too

Comment: For the xpath cod suggested 

Listening on port 13425
Only local connections are allowed
Nov 09, 2017 8:56:09 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='WD91']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:12:07.291Z'

Comment: yes now the first suggestion is not working.... i tried many times... first run though it worked.. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: I have requirement only to use IE and cannot use any other browsers :(

Comment: I think the button is in clicable state always when it is clicked i guess this is an issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared we need to try to click on the `<a>` tag as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='WD91' and @class='urLnkFunction urTxtStd']")).click();
```

You can also try to click on the `<img>` tag as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='WD91' and @class='urLnkFunction urTxtStd']/img[contains(@src,'//www.myhomemsn.com/')]")).click();
```